# How to set a define through "./configure" with Autoconf

Tags: c++, autotools, configure, autoconf, automake

I have one project that can generate two diferent applications based on one define.

```
libfoo_la_CXXFLAGS = -DMYDEFINE
```

I have to modify the Makefile.am to set this define, so it is not automatic.

Can I set this define somehow through the configure command?
Is there any other way to set one define using autotools?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new using autotools and I cant understand mostly of its documentation. Can you be more clear for me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to edit the file `configure.ac`, and before `AC_OUTPUT` (which is the last thing in the file) add a call to [`AC_DEFINE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Defining-Symbols.html).

In a simple case like yours, it should be enough with:

```
AC_DEFINE(MYDEFINE)
```

If you want to set a value, you use:

```
AC_DEFINE(MYDEFINE, 123)
```

This last will add `-DMYDEFINE=123` to the flags (`DEFS =` in Makefile), and `#define MYDEFINE 123` in the generated autoconf header if you use that.

I recommend you read the documentation from the beginning, and work through their examples and tutorials. Also check other projects' configure files to see how they use different features.

**Edit:** If you want to pass flags on the command line to the `make` command, then you do something like this:

```
libfoo_la_CXXFLAGS = $(MYFLAGS)
```

Then you call `make` like this:

```
$ make MYFLAGS="-DMYDEFINE"
```

If you don't set `MYFLAGS` on the command line, it will be undefined and empty in the makefile.

You can also set target-specific `CPPFLAGS` in `Makefile.am`, in which case the source files will be recompiled, once for each set of flags:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la libbar.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = foo.c
libfoo_la_CPPFLAGS = -DFOO
libbar_la_SOURCES = foo.c
libbar_la_CPPFLAGS = -DBAR
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I haven't been that clear. I have to set this define to create an executable, but I need to compile the same source code without this define to create another executable. Can I set this define some other way on command line?

Comment: @LuizAntonio Added how to add make-variables on the command line

Comment: Remark: You're meant to set `-D` flags in `AM_CPPFLAGS`,`libfoo_la_CPPFLAGS` or `bar_CPPFLAGS`, as it's a preprocessor flag.

Comment: I think Carlo's answer is more correct. Using the pattern above I get `/usr/bin/autoheader failed with exit status: 1` (after a few other warnings).

Answer (score 13):

These days autoheader demands

```
AC_DEFINE([MYDEFINE], [1], [Description here])
```